# -webkit-print-color-adjust is not working

Tags: css

```
span.lot_number_text{
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color:#a94442;
    padding-left:10px;
    color-adjust: exact;
}
```

It always shows black text instead of the color I declare. How can I fix this thing?

Comment: What is the code you are using this in? You may need to provide more context for answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust) (emphasis mine)

> The `-webkit-print-color-adjust` property is a non-standard CSS extension that can be used to force printing of **background colors** and **images** in browsers based on the WebKit engine.

> `exact`
>      **Background colors** and **images** of the element to which this rule is applied are always printed, user's print settings are overridden.

So what it means is that this affects only background colors and images, not `color`.

And what it implies is that **only** Chrome's "*Background graphics*" option <sub>(available under "*More Settings*" dropdown)</sub> is being overridden.

The "*Color: Black and white*" one can not be overridden by this property.